# adding Shard in runtime to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We have some servers that serve a specific amount of data (5TB).

The problem is that we have lack in space o the servers and we want to add another server.
The question is, what'll happend when I'll add the new `shard` while all the other servers already running?
Will MongoDB be possible to transfer the data to the new server?

Comment: You can add new shards without downtime, it will attempt to balance chunks out to the new shard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were commented on right away and the response is correct. What will simply happen is that the [balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-sharded-cluster-balancer/) will *periodically* attempt to re-allocate chunks across the available shards, including the new one.

The process is automatic after the `shard` is added so **yes** is is possible to transfer new data to the server.

Perhaps the main consideration (as pointed to in the document link) is that the **balancer** is applied on *one* instance of `mongos` you have running and of how the balancer behaves. A lot will depend on your configutation, but for more information read the following document in addition:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-balancing/#sharding-balancing-internals